# Can't switch to number keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

My app won't allow users to switch keyboards to the number/character keyboard. [image: gif showing lack of keyboard response]

I don't have anything in my UI Inspector showing over the bottom of the screen.

[image: UI Inspector]

I am truly stumped as to what could be causing this issue. Whatever it is blocks the number/symbol switcher, the keyboard language (or Emoji) selector, and the speech to text button. The space bar and return key on the same row continue to operate fine.

The affected UITextField's are subclassed, the keyboard works as expected on the other 5 views in which they are contained, but here is their code:

JCTextField.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface JCTextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable UIColor *underlineColor;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat underlineWidth;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBInspectable UIImage *sideImage;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat internalOffset;
@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat borderOffset;

@end
```

JCTextField.m

```
#import "JCTextField.h"

@implementation JCTextField

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self != nil) {
        self.underlineColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.underlineWidth = 1;
        self.internalOffset = 0;
        self.borderOffset = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CALayer *border = [CALayer layer];
    border.borderColor = _underlineColor.CGColor;
    border.frame = CGRectMake(_borderOffset, self.frame.size.height - _underlineWidth, self.frame.size.width - (_borderOffset * 2), self.frame.size.height);
    border.borderWidth = _underlineWidth;
    [self.layer addSublayer:border];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


    [self setValue:[UIColor lightTextColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
    [self setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:16.0]];


    if (self.sideImage) {
        UIImageView *sideImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - 30, 0, 30, 30)];
        sideImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        sideImageView.image = self.sideImage;
        [self addSubview:sideImageView];
    }

    [self setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [self setValue:[UIColor lightGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];

}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    if (self.sideImage) {
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, _internalOffset, 0, 18);
        return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets)];
    }
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, _internalOffset, 0, 0);
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets)];
}

- (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    if (self.sideImage) {
        UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, _internalOffset, 0, 18);
        return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets)];
    }
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, _internalOffset, 0, 0);
    return [super textRectForBounds:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, insets)];
}

@end
```

Comment: The obvious question is: is there anything special about your text field's `keyboardType` or any other weird stuff it does?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Its in Objective-C, fully native all done in Xcode.

Comment: @matt I am using a subclassed textfield, but I am using that same subclassed textfield all over (handles the UI) and the keyboard works as intended on the other 5 views they are used on.

Comment: Nevertheless, the fact that the text field is a subclass might be significant. You have not shown the subclass code, so that must remain a guess; only you can think about this (unless you want to share the code).

Comment: @matt Added the code to the textfields.

Comment: Well, your code is nutty, as I suppose you know. Overriding `drawRect:` for a text field is not supported, and _your_ override is kind of crazy because you aren't even drawing, but just adding sublayers and stuff  — and since `drawRect:` can be called a lot, you are ending up with a boatload of sublayers and things. In a way it seems like you are just misusing `drawRect:` to initialize the physical configuration of the text field. Why do that? Why not initialize once, in a proper place? I'm not saying this is the cause of your troubles, but I would strongly advise fixing this anyway, first.

Comment: @matt Removed my `drawRect:` method as suggested, as you expected it did not solve the initial issue. But it did help performance a bit.

Comment: Not surprised about that! :) Thanks for doing that, since it takes out one possible source of trouble. Of course now your fields don't look right, but you can fix that later. — So you say the keyboard works as intended "on the other 5 views". So what does "view" mean here? Can we isolate _anything_ that is special about _this_ one? (Either the view itself or its view controller, since we have a responder chain to worry about too.)

Comment: @matt, this view is a UIViewController with a Container View embedded a UITableViewController. The tableview controller contains custom TableView Cells that handle each section of data input. The other views that utilize this subclassed textfield are a mixture of similar UIViewController->Container->UITableView's and just plain UIViewControllers. Interestingly enough (just noticed this), after going to the problematic view, the keyboard stops working properly app-wide.

Comment: You should have a look at the lifecycle of UIViews. layoutSubviews is neither a good place for the view to setup or change. It can also be called multiple times (e.g. adding new views to it's parent) and is supposed for layouting (setting frames) none of the other stuff you do in each layout pass. You should implement all your view modifications in your own methods and then call setNeedsLayout() from there if the layout may have changed (e.g. with the font) or setNeedsDisplay() in other cases (e.g. color changes).